# LocationListener never called

Tags: android, android-location

I am trying to debug my application and for some reason I am never getting updates to my LocationListener when I start fetching current location...  I have added the correct permissions in the manifest. Here is an example code snippet I am using to test if at least one callback gets called:

I have tested on three different devices (Galaxy S3, Galaxy Note 2, Google Nexus 4) that have GPS & NETWORK enabled.

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                MyLog.debug("FOO");
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                MyLog.debug("FOO");
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                MyLog.debug("FOO");
            }

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                MyLog.debug("FOO");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Sure you have enabled logging in the 'MyLog' class?

Comment: Positive. It is just a wrapper to a the Log to automatically set the TAG. Other logs are being printed using the 'MyLog' class

Comment: have you tried a test gps app like [GPS Status & Toolbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2) to see if gps is working?

Comment: Yea looks like it cannot find a gps signal... Weird. But it still should work for using the network provider and it doesnt...

Comment: Try a value more than 0 for minimum distance or minimum time...

Answer (score -1):

Check you've added the right permissions in your manifest (`ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` or `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`).

Moreover you shouldn't specify a provider name like `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER`, because user may have disabled his gps on his device. `LocationManager` provides a  method `getBestProvider()`, you should call this method to get the best available provider.